# Excel Vlookup in pandas

Tags: pandas, vlookup

I'm trying to do something similar to a `Vlookup` (from Excel) without merging or joining dataframes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})

if left['key'] == right['key']:
    left['nome'] = right['value']
```

The response was:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, since I'm not familiar with vlookup, but it seems like you are trying to do a left merge of `left` and `right`, maybe? Such that the `value` column becomes the `nome` column?  If so, try the code below.  If not, please clarify your desired output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(0)
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})


pd.merge(left, right.rename(columns={'value':'nome'}), 
    left_on='key', right_on='key',how='left')
```

output:

| key | value | nome |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1.764052 | NaN |
| 1 | B | 0.400157 | 1.867558 |
| 2 | C | 0.978738 | NaN |
| 3 | D | 2.240893 | -0.977278 |